# SQL pivot table without using pivot function

Tags: sql-server

I need to convert a table from a standard table into a more summarized version. The rows should be based whether its the year 2013 or 2014. I was considering using a pivot but I don't believe its necessary. The code below fails because of the group by function of a column Ive just created is there a way to get around this?

CODE

```
CREATE VIEW -- select * from 
    [03_rdm].[AR_LedgerByInvoice] 
as
select [EY_Business_Unit]
        ,(Case when [AR_Fiscal Year] = 2014 then 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)' else 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)' end) [Aging_Bucket]
        , [AR_1-30 Days Past Due]
        , [AR_31-60 Days Past Due]
        , [AR_61-90 Days Past Due]
FROM [02_cdm].[0040_AR_InvoiceSummary_2013_2014]
GROUP BY [Aging_Bucket]
```

The end result should be:

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Business Unit   Aged Bucket                [AR_1-30 Days]   [AR_31-60 Days] [AR_61-90 Days] Total
100 `           AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)  x                xx             xxx             xxxx
100             AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)  x                xx             xxx             xxxx
```

Comment: Very unclear. You seem to want grouping but you aren't aggregating anything – what do you need grouping for then? Please consider posting a sample of the table you want to create the view on and the desired output *based on that sample*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't group by an alias created on the same 'level' but you should be able to group by the same expression, but maybe you just want to group by year? (if so maybe `GROUP BY [AR_Fiscal Year]` is what you really want):

```
CREATE VIEW -- select * from 
    [03_rdm].[AR_LedgerByInvoice] 
as
select [EY_Business_Unit]
        ,(Case when [AR_Fiscal Year] = 2014 then 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)' else 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)' end) [Aging_Bucket]
        , [AR_1-30 Days Past Due]
        , [AR_31-60 Days Past Due]
        , [AR_61-90 Days Past Due]
FROM [02_cdm].[0040_AR_InvoiceSummary_2013_2014]
GROUP BY 
  [EY_Business_Unit],
  CASE WHEN [AR_Fiscal Year] = 2014 THEN 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)' ELSE 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)' END
```

As you didn't provide any sample data or table I couldn't test it, but it should work.

Or maybe you want to aggregate the rows:

```
select [EY_Business_Unit]
        ,(Case when [AR_Fiscal Year] = 2014 then 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)' else 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)' end) [Aging_Bucket]
        , SUM([AR_1-30 Days Past Due])
        , SUM([AR_31-60 Days Past Due])
        , SUM([AR_61-90 Days Past Due])
FROM [0040_AR_InvoiceSummary_2013_2014]
GROUP BY 
[EY_Business_Unit]
        ,(Case when [AR_Fiscal Year] = 2014 then 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY)' else 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)' end)
order by [EY_Business_Unit];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get error that Business unit is not is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Its a never ending cycle to add all the columns which negates the group by function

Comment: Hmm, yeah. Do you need grouping though? You don't use any aggregate functions, so wouldn't just order by do it? Try excluding the group by all together.

Comment: Unfortunately it need to be condensed to two rows 'AR_Outstanding_Amount (CY) and AR_Outstanding_Amount (PY)

Comment: @Calgar99 Look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0414/1). How is this output different from what you want? I'm not saying it isn't, I just don't quite get what you need. Maybe if you provide some sample source data it would be easier to understand.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfede/1 I amended the SQL fiddle you created, as you can see for business unit 100 there are now three entries when we desire only a summary of 2. PY AND CY

Comment: @Calgar99 So there can be multiple rows for the same year/business unit? Do you want them summed up or use the max value or what is the plan to handle them? I put two versions in the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfede/5

Comment: OMG!!!! I feel like such a fool. I CANT BELIEVE I FORGOT TO SUM.......... Thank you for your patience